# Visual c++, resize a control on mousedown

Tags: winforms, winapi, visual-c++, winforms-interop

I made a `UserControl`library that contains several regular Button control.

i would like to resize it on drag.
dragdetction is done via windows messages and it seams to work flawless.

I even managed to set a correct cursor and .. back on `WM_MOUSELEAVE`.

```
virtual void WndProc( Message %m ) override
{
    // Listen for operating system messages
    switch ( m.Msg )
    {
        // more code
        // .
        // ..
        // ...
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            if(m.WParam.ToInt32() ==  MK_CONTROL)
            {
                Debug::WriteLine("MK_CONTROL");
                return;
            }
            else if(m.WParam.ToInt32() ==  MK_LBUTTON)
            {
                Debug::WriteLine("MK_LBUTTON");
                if(isMouseDown)
                {
                    Debug::WriteLine("drag Detected");
                    Debug::WriteLine("isMouseDown: " + isMouseDown.ToString());
                    int tempX = (short)(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0x0000FFFF);
                        this->Size.Width = (this->Location.X - tempX); // <--- does not work!
                    return;
                }
                return;
            }
            else if(m.WParam.ToInt32() ==  MK_MBUTTON)
            {
                Debug::WriteLine("MK_MBUTTON");
                return;
            }
            else if(m.WParam.ToInt32() ==  MK_RBUTTON)
            {
                Debug::WriteLine("MK_RBUTTON");
                return;
            }
            else if(m.WParam.ToInt32() ==  MK_SHIFT)
            {
                Debug::WriteLine("MK_SHIFT");
                return;
            }
            else if(m.WParam.ToInt32() ==  MK_XBUTTON1)
            {
                Debug::WriteLine("MK_XBUTTON1");
                return;
            }
            else if(m.WParam.ToInt32() ==  MK_XBUTTON2)
            {
                Debug::WriteLine("MK_XBUTTON2");
                return;
            }   
        return;
        // more code
        // .
        // ..
        // ...
        return;
    }
    System::Windows::Forms::UserControl::WndProc( m );
}
```

this However `this->Size.Width = (this->Location.X - e->Location.X);` // <--- does not work!
`this->Size.Width` will stay on it's default value of 400 previously set by the properties windows.

I know it's possible to set the size via windows messages, but i fail to understand how.
taken from a C# example:
[Controls won't get resized once the nesting hierarchy of windows exceeds a certain depth](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/11/20/controls-won-t-get-resized-once-the-nesting-hierarchy-of-windows-exceeds-a-certain-depth-x64.aspx)

```
    // this doesn't seam the right synthax for C++
    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool SetWindowPos(HandleRef hWnd, HandleRef hWndInsertAfter,
    int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int flags);
```

`UserControl` does not have a property/methode called `SetWindowPos`

How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Size property returns a strucutre, which is value type. So you get a copy, which you modify, but the original stays the same. To change form's size, you can set:

this->Size = new Size(100, 100);

or better, use Width and Height propetries:

this->Width += 100;

Comment: you're right `this->Width`, somthing happend... although, i can't figur out ... what exactly ... on it.